# Where does pyodbc get its user and pwd from when none are provided in the connection string

Tags: python, database, permissions, pyodbc

I inherited a project and am having what seems to be a permissions issue when trying to interact with the database. Basically we have a two step process of detach and then delete.

Does anyone know where the user would come from if the connection string only has driver, server, and database name.

EDIT
I am on Windows Server 2008 standard
EDIT
"DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;" Where driver is "SQL Server"

Comment: Have you checked the `.connect()` call to see if `UID` and `PWD` are being supplied as keyword parameters? (Also, I assume that the connection string or `.connect()` call does not include `Trusted_connection=yes`.)

Comment: Can you include the connection string from the Python code? Specifically, what does it say after "Driver="?

Comment: I just checked and it does not pass anything into the connect if no uid is provided. @GordThompson

Comment: Driver = SQL Server @FlipperPA

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer, hopefully it has everything you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a few tests and the `{SQL Server}` ODBC driver apparently defaults to using Windows Authentication if the `Trusted_connection` and `UID` options are both omitted from the connection string. So, your Python script must be connecting to the SQL Server instance using the Windows credentials of the user running the script.

(On the other hand, the `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` driver seems to default to SQL Authentication unless `Trusted_connection=yes` is included in the connection string.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on Windows, a few things you should know:

- Using the `Driver={SQL Server}` only enables features and data types
  supported by SQL Server 2000. For features up through 2005, use `{SQL
  Native Client}` and for features up through 2008 use `{SQL Server
  Native Client 10.0}`.
- To view your ODBC connections, go to Start and search for "ODBC" and
  bring up `Data Sources (ODBC)`. This will list User, System, and File
  DSNs in a GUI. You should find the DSN with username and password
  filled in there.

Comment: Good to know about the Native bit that will be useful. 
The User DSN only has dBaseFiles, Excel Files, and MS Access Database, System is empty, as is file. I see no record of username anywhere even in the ODBC registry. I wonder if it was just not set-up right.